# Как заставить бота телеграмм периодически отправлять сообщения?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, telebot

Всем привет, сделал рабочий парсер телеграмм. Хочу сделать чтобы он автоматически (спустя определенный промежуток времени) отправлял прайс. На данный момент отправляет только по нажатию команды /price.

код:

```
import requests
import telebot
from config import token
from datetime import datetime

def get_data():
    req = requests.get("https://yobit.net/api/3/ticker/btc_usd")
    response = req.json()
    print(response)
    sell_price = response["btc_usd"]["sell"]
    print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')}\nSell BTC price: {sell_price}")
    volume = response["btc_usd"]["vol"]
    print(f"\namount BTC: {volume}")


def telegram_bot(token):
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

    @bot.message_handler(commands=["price"])
    def send_text(message):

        if message.text.lower() == "/price":
            try:

                req = requests.get("https://yobit.net/api/3/ticker/btc_usdt")
                response = req.json()
                sell_price = response["btc_usdt"]["sell"]
                volume = response["btc_usdt"]["vol"]
                bot.send_message(
                    message.chat.id,
                    f"{datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')}\nSell BTC price: {sell_price}"
                    f"\nVolume: {volume}")

            except Exception as ex:
                print(ex)
                bot.send_message(
                    message.chat.id,
                    "Damn...Something was wrong...")

    bot.polling()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   #get_data()
   #get_data2()
   telegram_bot(token)
```

Comment: используй библиотеку schedule

Answer (score 1):

Я сделал, немного криво но сделал. В начале кода приписал тайм слип просто и всё. Может пригодится кому.

[image]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст ответа можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа.